# Python get line number in file

Tags: python, file, parsing, line-numbers

I built a python (2.7) script that parses a txt file with this code:

```
cnt = 1

logFile = open( logFilePath, 'r' )

for line in logFile:
    if errorCodeGetHostName in line:
        errorHostNameCnt = errorHostNameCnt + 1
        errorGenericCnt = errorGenericCnt + 1
        reportFile.write( "--- Error: GET HOST BY NAME @ line " + str( cnt ) + "\n\r" )
        reportFile.write( line )


    elif errorCodeSocke462 in line:
        errorSocket462Cnt = errorSocket462Cnt + 1
        errorGenericCnt = errorGenericCnt + 1
        reportFile.write("--- Error: SOCKET -462 @ line " + str(cnt) + "\n\r" )
        reportFile.write(line)


    elif errorCodeMemory in line:
        errorMemoryCnt = errorMemoryCnt + 1
        errorGenericCnt = errorGenericCnt + 1
        reportFile.write("--- Error: MEMORY NOT RELEASED @ line " + str(cnt) + "\n\r" )
        reportFile.write(line)

    cnt = cnt + 1
```

I want to add the line number of each error, and for this purpose I added a counter (cnt) but its value is not related to to the real line number.

This is a piece of my log file:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2017.06.13 17:05:43 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
UTC Time fetched from server #1: '0.pool.ntp.org'


   *** Test (cycle #1) starting...
   --- Test01 completed successfully!
   --- Test02 completed successfully!
   --- Test03 completed successfully!
   --- Test04 completed successfully!
   --- Test01 completed successfully!
   --- Test02 completed successfully!
INF:[CONFIGURATION] Completed
   --- Test03 completed successfully!
Firmware Version: 0.0.0


   *** Test (cycle #1) starting...
```

How can I get the real line number?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: use `enumerate` instead

Comment: Is there a `cnt = 1` somewhere and you just didn't include that line? Otherwise, this code looks okay. What do you mean when you say "its value is not related to the real line number?"

Comment: i agree with @smarx ,cnt actually would do the job

Comment: cnt is initialized to 1. I haven't add cnt to example. Sorry. (Fixed). My first error is at line 258 but in my report file the error is signled at line 240.

Comment: Why don't you print `line` and `cnt` at each iteration of the loop to see where things are going awry?

Comment: Then check again your line 240, to see why an error was detected there.

Comment: Should the problem regards the "\n\r"? In the file there are consecutive "\n\r" but parser recognises only on "\n\r".

Comment: When you print `line` and `cnt` at each iteration, where's the first line that doesn't match up what you expect? The problem should become obvious once you do this.

Comment: The first unmatch is after a double return. I have 2 blank lines in the file but the counter in incremented only one time.

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue. What operating system are you on? Have you tried "rt" mode in the `open` call? What are the line endings in the file?

Comment: I added a pice of log. I use windows but the log comes from Putty that reads on a serial port connected to an embedded device. In the original log, on Notepad++ some lines end only with LF.

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to the lines where ends with LF?

Answer (score 1):

apart from the line-ending issue, there are some other issues with this code

## Filehandles

as remarked in on of the comments, it is best to open files with a `with`-statement

## Separation of functions

Now you have 1 big loop where you both loop over the original file, parse it and immediately write to the `ReportFile`. I think it would be best to separate those.

Make one function to loop over the log, return the details you need, and a next function looping over these details and writing them to a report. this is a lot more robust, and easier to debug and test when something goes wrong

I would also let the IO as much outside as possible. If you later want to stream to a socket or something, this can be easily done

## DRY

Lines 6 to 24 of your code contain a lot of lines that are almost the same, and if you want to add another error you want to report, you need to add another 5 lines of code, almost the same. I would use a `dict` and a for-loop to cut on the boilerplate-code

## Pythonic

A smaller remark is that you don't use the handy things Python offers, like `yield` the `with`-statement, `enumerate` or `collections.counter` Also variable naming is not according to `PEP-8`, but that is mainly aesthetic

## My attempt

```
errors = {
    error_hostname_count: {'error_msg' = '--- Error: GET HOST BY NAME @ line %i'},
    error_socker_462: {'error_msg' = '--- Error: SOCKET -462 @ line %i'},
    error_hostname_count: {'error_msg' = '--- Error: MEMORY NOT RELEASED @ line %i'},
    }
```

Here you define what errors can occur and what the error message should look like

```
def get_events(log_filehandle):
    for line_no, line in enumerate(log_filehandle):
        for error_code, error in errors.items():
            if error_code in line:
                yield line_no, error_code, line
```

This just takes a filehandle (can be a Stream or Buffer too) and just looks for error_codes in there, if it finds one, it yields it together with the line

```
def generate_report(report_filehandle, error_list):
    error_counter = collections.Counter()
    for line_no, error_code, error_line in error_list:
        error_counter['generic'] += 1
        error_counter[error_code] += 1

        error_msg = format_error_msg(line_no, error_code)
        report_file.write(error_msg)
        report_file.write(error_line)
    return error_counter
```

This loops over the found errors. It increases they counter, formats the message and writes it to the report_file

```
def format_error_msg(line_no, error_code):
    return errors[error_code['error_msg'] % line_no
```

This uses string-formatting to generate a message from an error_code and line_no

```
with open(log_filename, 'r') as log_filehandle, open(report_filename, 'w') as report_filehandle:
    error_list = get_events(log_filehandle):
    error_counter = print_events(report_filehandle, error_list)
```

This ties it all together. You could use the `error_counter` to add a summary to the report, or write a summary to another file or database.

This approach has the advantage that if your error recognition changes, you can do this independent  of the reporting and vice-versa

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My python coding style is more similar to C. I have a little python  knowledge

Comment: I try your code and I get "can't assign to literal" on errors.

Comment: What line is giving the error? And since I didn't know what the error_codes were, you will have to assign some of the values for this to work

Comment: at line 7. Could you provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Intro: the log that I want parse is coming from an embedded platform programmed in C.

I found into the embedded code, that somewhere there are a printf with **\n\r** instead of **\r\n**. I replace each **\n\r** with **\r\n** that correspond to windows **CR LF**.

With this change the python script works! And I can identify the error by its line.